# Bluez 5.37 install problem

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I'm new on the forum and on Raspberry too... I'm trying to install Bluez 5.37 on my Raspberry because I need to power on a Sitecom Bluetooth USB dongle. This dongle need this version to go in HCI mode, the version with `apt-get` doesn't have the csr2 mode.

So I started with the installation from source but when I provide the make command the following error is returned:

```
src/plugin.c: In function ‘plugin_init’:
src/plugin.c:139:14: error: ‘__bluetooth_builtin’ undeclared (first use in this function)
for (i = 0; __bluetooth_builtin[i]; i++) {
^
src/plugin.c:139:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Makefile:8106: recipe for target 'src/bluetoothd-plugin.o' failed
make[1]: *** [src/bluetoothd-plugin.o] Error 1
Makefile:9157: recipe for target 'check' failed
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

Previously, the `./configure` command goes well.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Might be `genbuiltin` permission problem.

I tried to give `src/genbuiltin` and `obexd/src/genbuiltin` -x (execute) permission, and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I installed `alsa` which then solved the problem.

Comment: [alsa](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page)? How does that help? Can you edit your answer and provide a command line, or GUI, method for installing the package?